# Vue js 2 как отобразить выбранный атрибут в select

Tags: javascript, vue.js

есть такой код

```
    <div id="watch-example">
        <select v-model="selected">
          <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">
            {{ option.text }}
          </option>
        </select>
        <span>Выбрано: {{ selected }}</span>
    </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var watchExampleVM = new Vue({
      el: '#watch-example',
      data: {
        selected: 'A',
        options: [
          { text: 'One', value: 'A' },
          { text: 'Two', value: 'B' },
          { text: 'Three', value: 'C' }
        ]
      }
    })
```

http://codepen.io/des1roer/pen/gmWZgO

а вот если я хочу отобразить выбранный текст (One, Two, Three) как быть?

cам код из

[http://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Выпадающие-списки](http://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: Очень неудобная форма для этого. Есть возможность переделать?

Comment: не понимаю про что речь

Comment: Есть возможность исправить массив `options`?

Comment: я новичок в фреймворке. не знаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#watch-example',
  data: {
    selected: 'A',
    options: {
      A: 'One',
      B: 'Two',
      C: 'Three'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="watch-example">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <!-- value будет ключами, т. е. "A", "B", "C", как и требовалось -->
    <option v-for="(text, key) in options" :value="key">
      {{ text }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <!-- Просто извлекаем значение по ключу -->
  <span>Выбрано: {{ options[selected] }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: как ссылка http://codepen.io/des1roer/pen/zZwejO

Comment: @des1roer, можно и так.